# Ratio of Means of two numbers 10 and 100

Tags: ratio

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db1It.jpg)

I was reading a book on computer architecture for my exam and came across this table. I understand all the columns except for the ratio of means. How is the ratio of means of 10 and 100 become 91.8. I would really appreciate if someone can provide me with an explanation.

Comment: Can you add some more context or cite properly the book?

Comment: Book: “Parallel Computer Organization and Design”Michel Dubois, Murali Annavaram, and Per Stenström. Page 21. The thing is there is no explanation of how the math was done in the book. I have uploaded the full page from the book: https://imgur.com/f7aa2LG & https://imgur.com/JDDkbga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column "ratios of means" is the ratio of arithmetic means of the reference and of the machines: so the first is "reference1"/"machine1" (5050/55), the second is "reference1"/"machine2" (5050/100.5), the third is "reference2/machine1" and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect explanation. Should have uploaded the full page from the beginning!